# how to change default virtual keyboard of device

Tags: android

I have a task to send an email by using intent without using xml layout,
it works fine but here my issue is to change the keypad appears with enter option  by default but here i need it to replace done option.
How can i get it?

Here my code:

```
 Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Brown University: "
                    + gTitle_val);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html
                    .fromHtml("<p><a href=\"" + gLink_web_url_val + "\">"
                            + gTitle_val + "</a></p><br><p>" + gContent_val
                            + "</p>"));
            sendIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Email:"
                    + gTitle_val));
```

Comment: You mean inside the email app?

Comment: yes,when i execute the above it opens mail to send it have three edittext field to enter our data,for each field it have virtual keypad with enter option at right corner,but i need it to be done button.is it possible to do it.